# Congruence relations and congruence modulo m

Tags: notation, congruence-relations

What are some congruence relations apart from congruence modulo $m$?

Also, is the congruence modulo $m$ called that way because the sets of all the integers $0,1, ..., m-1$ form an isomorphic group under addition mod $ m$ to the group of rotations of an $m$-sided polygon?

Comment: Are you using "congruence relation" in the sense of (universal) algebra, i.e. an equivalence relation compatible with the operations?

Comment: Yes, in that sense.

Comment: Do you mean on Z (integers)? There are *no* other congruences in this ring! Any other equivalence relation on Z is *not* a congruence. If you're asking for examples on other rings, please make that clear. (Some answered with an example on a ring of polynomials, but you didn't upvote that.)

Answer (score 0):

An important congruence relation is congruence modulo a polynomial.

For instance, one construction of the complex numbers is $\mathbb R[x] \bmod (x^2+1)$.

More generally, if $p(x)$ is an irreducible polynomial over a field $K$, then $K[x] \bmod f(x)$ is a field containing a root of $f$.
(The standard notation is $K[x]/(f(x))$.)